# How to handle memory allocation in C

Tags: c

I am new in C and i am creating a simple program in which i am writing value to the multidimensional error .But I am getting error `"Segmentation fault"` or some time when i am running the code it is getting in Infinite loop.

```
int main(){
int i,j;
int num1=10; 
int num2=10; 
double data[num1][num2];


    for(i=0;i<=num1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=num2;j++){
            if(i==0) {
                data[i][j]=121.21;
            }
            else {
                data[i][j]=0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i am doing the hardcoding of values on below structure it is working fine :
change `double data[num1][num2];` to `double data[10][10];`

How can we fix this issue in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overrunning the bounds of the array in your loops:

```
for(i=0;i<=num1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<=num2;j++){
```

In the outer loop `i` ranges from 0 to `num1`, while in the inner loop `j` ranges from 0 to `num2`.  However, the maximum valid index for each array dimension is `num1-1` and `num2-1` respectively.  Reading / writing past the end of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which is why it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't.

Change the loop conditions to `<`:

```
for(i=0;i<num1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<num2;j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going over the memory the program is allowing you to access. You are allocating memory for 100 values (10*10). However, when dealing with arrays in most programming languages, it is important that you know index 0 counts as one such that you can go from array[0] - array[9] and that is declaring an array with memory for 10 spots since we start at 0 in most programming languages.

A clean way to fix this code would be:

```
for (int i=0; i < num1; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < num2; j++ {
```

This would avoid accessing memory location at index 10 which is not allocated.